# Unable to locate the uploaded document using Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, sql-database

I have created a Sitecore form where I am added a *File Upload* button and uploaded a file. Also, I have used the `Save Data` option to save the data to the Database once I click submit button.

Now I can able to see the data in the database in the table `[sitecore_forms_filestorage].[FileStorage]` with the Filename field containing the name of the file I uploaded. For example, I have uploaded a word document named "Test Document.docx" and it is showing in the database. But I have no idea where the physical document is stored in Sitecore.

I have searched in Media Library but it is not present. I need to retrieve this document and allow the user to edit the document which I am currently not able to do. Can you please help me how to find the uploaded document in Sitecore? I have attached screenshots of the forms and data for reference.

[image: Forms Designer]

[image: Forms DB Table]

Thanks in Advance
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a form in the `Form Panel` and export the data in excel like below.

[image]

You will get the data in excel along with the file path to download like this.

[image]

Now when you open this URL in the browser, you will be able to download the file.

So You can use this way to get your uploaded file.

If you want to manage the file storage for the form, then you can follow this Sitecore document to do the modifications.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/manage-file-storage-for-forms.html

Hope this help.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi Sumit, Thanks for your help. It worked for me. I am able to download the document from the excel file. Sorry for the delayed reply.